# Syntax highlighting is inconsistent

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279407/why-does-copying-elements-one-by-one-outperform-array-copy-for-a-small-array-of), why is `ElementByElement` highlighted as a method, but `ElementByElement2` isn't?

EDIT: To submit a new issue to Prettify, I'd like to know what version Stack Overflow uses. 21-May-2009? Some other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Syntax highlighting is not part of the SO source; it is accomplished using [google prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). Suggest improvements to them instead.

Comment: What version of Prettify does SO use?

Comment: I don't come to stackoverflow.com to use prettify, I come to use StackOverflow. The fact that they use Google Prettify is merely an implementation detail. It's up to the SO team to decide whether to keep doing that or replace the implementation with something else.  All I know (as a user) is that I want my code to look good.

Answer (score 2):

We just deployed the latest trunk of prettify.js ; revision 83

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.js