# Keyword 'let' from LINQ syntax is not supported by syntax highlighting

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, code-formatting

I found that neither on SO. nor here, on meta, LINQ syntax keyword `let` isn't being highlighted:

```
from f in db.Foo
let b = f.Bar
where b.Count == 1
select new FooBar(b);
```

Please add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Stack Overflow uses a generic syntax highlighting algorithm this is always going to happen. For any given language some words will be highlighted inappropriately others won't be highlighted at all. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14549/syntax-highlighting-is-inconsistent) for another example.

Unless they change the markdown so you can specify the language this will remain unfixable. See [Syntax highlighting hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-hints)

Comment: If you want to have fun with the syntax highlighting just make a VB sample with comments

Comment: @Matthew: This is the most annoying behavior of this highlighter and I don't know why it isn't fixed yet!

Comment: But if they have `from`, `where` and `select` on the list of blue-highlighted keywords, can't they just add `let` to the list? So there will be a few more false-positives - no one will notice - there are a ton of them anyway...